# ANDROID : Unable to set action in CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE in my service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a service where I want to register for the the Broadcast action CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE (android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE) to update my online status. I am doing it in the following way

### Service OnCreate Method

```
final IntentFilter theFilter = new IntentFilter();
theFilter.addAction(android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE);

this.ConnStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         // Do whatever you need it to do when it receives the broadcast
         // Example show a Toast message...
    }
};
```

But while compilation it does not recognize the part **android.net.conn** in my **android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE**. Its is showing some package problem. Please help me in fixing this. As I am registering for broadcast receiver dynamically, I think no need to mention it in manifest file. Please suggest me. I am stuck up here.

Comment: Why negative vote? What's the problem with the question? Why can't you simply answer the question? If you are negative voting.. then give some comments why you are doing this....

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

```
theFilter.addAction(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you still need the solution but IntentFilter.addAction() receives a string so if you pass the string with the name to it, it works:

```
theFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
```

I agree that someone has been rude voting down without reason.